# Is Facebook PHP SDK oauth 1.0 or 2.0

Tags: php, facebook, api, sdk, oauth

I today got a mail to transform my application to oauth 2.0
I used the php sdk from facebook for the authentication purposes...
Is Facebook PHP SDK oauth 1.0 or 2.0

Answer (score 4):

[Facebook only uses Oauth 2](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/); so does the php sdk.

Answer (score 2):

PHP SDK v2.x is using Facebook;'s legacy auth.
PHP SDK v3.x is using OAuth 2

Answer (score 1):

The PHP SDK does not use oauth at this time. It uses the Facebook's legacy auth, which is neither oauth 1 or 2.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/connect_auth/

Also see Facebook's announcement here here: http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/497/?ref=nf

"Websites using JavaScript and PHP SDKs

On July 1, we will have an updated JavaScript SDK and PHP SDK available that supports the upgraded auth flows as well as a modified cookie format that includes the code parameter. Once ready, we will publish a post on the update. If you’re directly referencing the JavaScript SDK, this change will happen automatically. "

Comment: At the very top of the page you linked to: "We recently announced that all apps and sites must migrate to our OAuth 2.0 authentication mechanism by September 1, 2011. We released our OAuth implementation well over a year ago and many sites have already moved over."